# SQL query isn't returning data that it should

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is the data table, named "flagged_threads"

| flagged_threadID | threadID | userID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 | 1 |

And here is my attempt at selecting all threadID's correlated to user 1

```
$flagged_sql = "SELECT threadID FROM flagged_threads WHERE userID = 'current_userID'";
$flagged_qry = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $flagged_sql);
$flagged_aa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($flagged_qry);
```

$flagged_aa should return an array containing [2, 3, 6] correct?
at the moment it is only returning the first threadID it can find. Meaning it only returns [2] in this situation.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation for mysqli_fetch_assoc: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

You have to use this function in a loop like this:

```
$flagged_sql = "SELECT threadID FROM flagged_threads WHERE userID = 'current_userID'";
$flagged_qry = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $flagged_sql);

while($flagged_aa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($flagged_qry)) {
     // do something with $flagged_aa
}
```